# save data in android application even after app is closed without using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, text-files, android-sharedpreferences

hi guys i wanted to save data in android application but i dont want to use shared preferences concept. can i save data on a text file in phone and perform read/write operations on it evertime I open my app for example update hall of fame everytime when game is over?

Comment: save your values in Sqlite@Prakash Elugoti

Comment: Yes, you can use a file or a database or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of available options in the officional developer guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

The following options are explained there:

- Store data using shared preferences
- Save data to files on internal or external storage
- Store data in SQLite databases
- Store data on the web